# Parsing through Windows Dump File with WINDBg scripting

Tags: scripting, windbg

I am searching for a hex pattern in a windbg dump file (s 0 L?80000000 4D 00 69 00 63 00 72) and I would like to assign the memory address at which this pattern is found into a variable e.g. if windbg returns: 00b871b4  4d 00 69 00 63 I would like to store 00b871b4 into a variable and then perform some further calculations on this address. How can I assign the returned address into a variable via windbg script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are You Sure You will get only one result ?
s returns multiple returns if found

which result you want to assign ?

are you using a latest version of windbg ?

if yes then you can assign the result of an executed command to a variable 
and iterate either natively or using javascript

an example of multiple results

```
0:000> s 0 l?0x30000000 4d 5a
000aa37c  4d 5a 01 00 52 5a 01 00-58 5a 01 00 5e 5a 01 00  MZ..RZ..XZ..^Z..
000e0000  4d 5a 90 00 03 00 00 00-04 00 00 00 ff ff 00 00  MZ..............
000f0000  4d 5a 90 00 03 00 00 00-04 00 00 00 ff ff 00 00  MZ..............
00100000  4d 5a 90 00 03 00 00 00-04 00 00 00 ff ff 00 00  MZ..............
00150000  4d 5a 90 00 03 00 00 00-04 00 00 00 ff ff 00 00  MZ..............
00160000  4d 5a 90 00 03 00 00 00-04 00 00 00 ff ff 00 00  MZ..............
00170000  4d 5a 90 00 03 00 00 00-04 00 00 00 ff ff 00 00  MZ..............
00180000  4d 5a 90 00 03 00 00 00-04 00 00 00 ff ff 00 00  MZ..............
001967fe  4d 5a 00 00 66 39 05 00-00 18 00 75 55 8b 0d 3c  MZ..f9.....uU..<
00196c02  4d 5a 00 00 66 39 10 75-32 8b 50 3c 85 d2 78 2b  MZ..f9.u2.P<..x+
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
0ff50000  4d 5a 90 00 03 00 00 00-04 00 00 00 ff ff 00 00  MZ..............
0ffd0000  4d 5a 90 00 03 00 00 00-04 00 00 00 ff ff 00 00  MZ..............
0:000>
```

here is how you use the natvis expression evaluator dx

```
0:000> dx  @$foo = Debugger.Utility.Control.ExecuteCommand ("s 0 l?0x30000000 4d 5a")
@$foo = Debugger.Utility.Control.ExecuteCommand ("s 0 l?0x30000000 4d 5a")
    [0x0]            : 000aa37c  4d 5a 01 00 52 5a 01 00-58 5a 01 00 5e 5a 01 00  MZ..RZ..XZ..^Z..
    [0x1]            : 000e0000  4d 5a 90 00 03 00 00 00-04 00 00 00 ff ff 00 00  MZ..............
    [0x2]            : 00240000  4d 5a 90 00 03 00 00 00-04 00 00 00 ff ff 00 00  MZ..............
    [0x3]            : 00288979  4d 5a 00 00 66 39 08 74-04 33 c0 5d c3 8b 48 3c  MZ..f9.t.3.]..H<
    [0x4]            : 002bf505  4d 5a 00 00 66 39 01 75-f3 8b 41 3c 03 c1 81 38  MZ..f9.u..A<...8
    [0x5]            : 002d6bfb  4d 5a e8 0f fc ff ff 83-c4 14 84 c0 0f 84 9e fd  MZ..............
```

and use linq queries on the variable

```
0:000> dx @$foo.First()
@$foo.First()    : 000aa37c  4d 5a 01 00 52 5a 01 00-58 5a 01 00 5e 5a 01 00  MZ..RZ..XZ..^Z..
    Length           : 0x4b
0:000> dx @$foo.Last()
@$foo.Last()     : 104153e0  4d 5a 90 00 03 00 00 00-04 00 00 00 ff ff 00 00  MZ..............
    Length           : 0x4b
0:000> dx @$foo.First(a=>a.Contains("2400") ==true)
@$foo.First(a=>a.Contains("2400") ==true) : 00240000  4d 5a 90 00 03 00 00 00-04 00 00 00 ff ff 00 00  MZ..............
    Length           : 0x4b
0:000>
```

for old windbg you can assign using some convoluted tricks 
see below the Pseudo Register is assigned with the last address 
passing the -[1] flag with type bor w or d will result in printing of only the matching address and .foreach can be used on each of the result
here i am saving it as as a c++ pseudo regisater

```
0:000> .foreach ( val { s -[1]b 0 l?0x30000000 4d 5a} ) { r? $t0 = ((int *) val ) }
0:000> ? @$t0
Evaluate expression: 17067465 = 01046dc9
0:000> s -[1]b 0 l?0x30000000 4d 5a
0x000aa37c
0x01030000
0x010467fe
0x01046c02
0x01046dc9
0:000>
```

convert string to number and do arithmetic operations

```
0:000> dx @$foo= Debugger.Utility.Control.ExecuteCommand("s -[1]b 0 l?0x30000000 4d 5a")

@$foo= Debugger.Utility.Control.ExecuteCommand("s -[1]b 0 l?0x30000000 4d 5a")
    [0x0]            : 0x0024a37c
    [0x1]            : 0x00ef0000
    [0x2]            : 0x00f067fe
    [0x3]            : 0x00f06c02
    [0x4]            : 0x00f06dc9

0:000> $$ load a dummy scriptfile for taking advantage of host.namespace

0:000> .scriptload e:\wdjs\blank.js
JavaScript script successfully loaded from 'e:\wdjs\blank.js'


0:000> dx @$blah = @$scriptContents.host.parseInt64(@$foo[0],16)
@$blah = @$scriptContents.host.parseInt64(@$foo[0],16) : 0x24a37c

0:000> dx @$bar = @$blah + 15  << decimal here not hex
@$bar = @$blah + 15 : 0x24a38b

0:000> dx @$bar = @$blah + 0xf4  << hex needs forced qualification of 0x
@$bar = @$blah + 0xf4 : 0x24a470
0:000>
```

a javascript

```
function srchadd() 
{
    var exec = host.namespace.Debugger.Utility.Control.ExecuteCommand
    var hits = exec("s -[1]b 0 L?0x30000000 4d 5a")
    for ( i of hits )
    {
        j = host.parseInt64(i,16)
        k = j.add(15).toString()
        l = j.add(0xf4).toString()
        host.diagnostics.debugLog( j.toString() +" "+ k +" "+ l + "\n")
    }        
}
```

results of executing the javascript(each address has been manipulated)

```
0:000> .scriptload e:\wdjs\srchadd.js
JavaScript script successfully loaded from 'e:\wdjs\srchadd.js'
0:000> dx @$scriptContents.srchadd()
0xaa37c 0xaa38b 0xaa470
0xef0000 0xef000f 0xef00f4
0xf067fe 0xf0680d 0xf068f2
0xf06c02 0xf06c11 0xf06cf6
0xf06dc9 0xf06dd8 0xf06ebd
@$scriptContents.srchadd()
0:000>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response                                                                                          
"Are You Sure You will get only one result ? s returns multiple returns if found" - this particular query only returns a single result e.g. 00b871b4  4d 00 69 00 63 00 72 00-6f 00 73 00 6f 00 66 00

"which result you want to assign ?" - I want to assign the memory address returned by my search to the variable

"are you using a latest version of windbg ?" - No. I am using Windbg:6.12.0002.633 x86.       Any other way I could accomplish this with my current windbg version?

Comment: I found a newer machine with the latest windbg so I am now able to use the natvis expression evaluator dx and linq queries on the variable. I have been able to assign the memory address to the variable using dx @$foo = .   So I am almost there. Now i need a way to perform an arithmetic caculation with that variable say @$foo+15 or @$foo + F4 for example. Not too familiar with Linq queries so not sure how to write this out though.

Comment: since ExecuteCommand Returns String you cannot add a number to that output  you need  to either use javascript completely and convert strtonum and add or load a blank js and use host.parseInt64() on the string

Comment: added details take a look

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I was looking for. Will run this and let you know how it goes. Thank you